# Nexus 4, Lollipop 5.1 WiFi Issue

Tags: wi-fi, nexus-4, 5.1-lollipop

My Nexus 4 device stopped connecting to the Cisco router at work for some reason.  I thought it was because the upgrade to lollipop 5.0 (had Kit-Kat before) but I'm not so sure anymore.

**I tried:**

- Restart the device
- Restart the device with safe mode
- Restart the router
- Change the device WiFi frequency settings
- Use static IP at the advance WiFi connection configuration
- Forget the router AP and reconnect
- Factory reset trough the device settings, recovery mode and complete flashing the Android Lollipop 5.1 factory image.

After factory reset I had the connection possible until restarting the device.
I checked with/without signing in, nothing new installed, didn't visit the store, just super clean phone - I could connect the network. after restarting the phone I can no longer connect which means it's not an application issue.

**Some facts:**

- I can connect other Cisco routers at work
- Another Nexus 4 after factory reset connects with no trouble

**About the device:**

- Nexus 4
- Lollipop 5.1
- build number LMY470
- kernel version 3.4.0-perf-gf75bb4f

Any suggestion will be welcome, please let me know if I can provide more details.

Comment: It sounds like one of your apps is causing the problem. You may have to reload them one-by-one until you find the culprit.

Comment: sounds so. do you know an easy way to do it? should I restart after each app uninstallation?

Comment: That might be easier than a factory reset followed by installing one at a time until it stops working. The problem, though, is that the culprit app might have modified a setting that won't get cleared without a factory reset.

Comment: @JoeSewell It doesn't seems like app issue. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Some sites recommend to restart the router device, and sometime it works.
Instead of every time restart the router to solve this Android 5.1 Wi-Fi problem, it worked for me:

Inside the router configuration (e.g., accessing the IP 192.168.0.1), change the "Group key update" value from 0 to 30 seconds, under the "Wireless > Security" configuration, right below the WPA-PSK/WPA2-PSK item.

My router model is: TP-LINK TL-WR740N / TL-WR740ND.